# How to stop a scroll in löve2d?

Tags: lua, scroll, game-development, love2d

For my **fnaf fan game project**. I coded a prototype. But I've got *problem for the scrolling*, I've tried to stop it but I can't. So if someone can help it could be great !

That's the code (only update and draw functions)

```
function love.update(dt)
    player.x, player.y = love.mouse.getPosition()

    if reduce_back == 300 then
        reduce_back = reduce_back + 0
    end


    if player.x > 700 then             -- If the X position is over than 700 screen's pixel
        reduce_back = reduce_back + 25 -- There will have a scroll to the right
    elseif player.x < 60 then          -- If the X position is less than 60 screen's pixel
        reduce_back = reduce_back - 25 -- There will have a scroll to the left
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.scale(1)
    -- Draws the background
    for i = 0, love.graphics.getWidth() / background:getWidth() do
        for j = 0, love.graphics.getHeight() / background:getHeight() do
            love.graphics.draw(
                background,
                i * background:getWidth() - reduce_back, -- reduce_back is the variable I use for setting the camera to the middle and I also use it for scrolling
                j * background:getHeight()
            )
        end
    end

    -- love.graphics.print(player.x, 1080 / 2, 0)
    -- love.graphics.print(player.y, 1080 / 2, 15)


    if bonnie.layers:getLayer() == 1 then
        love.graphics.scale(0.18)
        love.graphics.draw(bonnie.image, 0, 0)
        player:setLife()
    end

    if not player.isAlive then
        bonnie:playScream()
    end

    love.graphics.print(reduce_back)
end
```

If you need all my code I can send it if you desire.

Comment: Please try to reduce the problem into a [mre] that can easily be tested.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to make an movable background(camera), then you should use an library for it, like hump (love2d hyper utility for massive progression).https://github.com/vrld/hump

```
camera = require 'lib/camera' --game Camera

cam = camera()
    function love.update(dt)
    cam:lookAt(player.x,player.y)
end

function love.draw()
    cam:attach()
    --[[all the things that will moveable object on screen(like player,level) ]]--
    cam:detach
    --[[all the other things that is not to be moved that is(score, ui,etc) ]]--

end
```